# node.js, socket.io - Is it normal connecting to socket server on every page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sockets

I'm developing a social network based on php, and I want users get realtime notifications and I decided to use socket.io and node.js. But is it normal that jquery connection will be realised in Header of website and every time when user moves another page he will be connected to socket server again and again?

I think it would be better to make ajax load of pages, but I can't move whole social network pages to ajax-friendly pages to realise it.

Comment: Yes it is normal, that's how socket.io works. What is the problem here?

Comment: @PascalMeunier Oh, I just didn't know it, I thought if it impact on RAM/Connection or something else. Thank you for your answer! Please post it as answer.